# How to check response in Jmeter so that each response should contain canonical link?

Tags: jmeter, seo, assertions

For example I've got list of URLs.
Each URL should contain the following parameter in the head of HTML body:

```
<link rel="canonical" href="http://example.com/xxx/yyy/zzz/">
```

Parameters which are displayed in "href", duplicate exact URL of request.

What type of assertion should I use and how to configure it in order to automatically check 7k+ of  URLs?

The main idea is to check the response code ( it should be 200 ) and that parameter in "href" has got the same value as URL .

Answer (score 1):

1. Extract URL

   - Add [Regular Expression Extractor](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/207421325-Using-RegEx-Regular-Expression-Extractor-with-JMeter) as a child of the request (or if you have a lot of requests put it on the same level as the requests) and configure it as follows:

     - Reference Name: anything meaningful, i.e. `url`
     - Regular Expression: `(.*)`
     - Template: `$1$`

       [image: JMeter Regex Extract URL]
2. Perform response validation.

   - Add [Response Assertion](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Response_Assertion) (the same [scope](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/test_plan.html#scoping_rules) as the Regular Expresion Extractor) and configure it as follows

     - Apply to: `Main sample only`
     - Pattern Matching Rules: `Substring`
     - Patterns to Test: `<link rel="canonical" href="${url}">`

       [image: JMeter Assertion Validate URL]